# Still getting old file content in .NET

Tags: .net, file, io

I have .NET 3.5 ClickOnce application. There is simple grid with list of Word documents, that are stored on the server. On button click, application downloads selected document from server (via WCF) and put it in the defined temp folder. Right after that, hash of the document is computed using following function:

```
Public Shared Function HashFile(ByVal file As String) As String
  Using reader As New System.IO.FileStream(file, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
    Using provider As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
      Dim hash() As Byte = provider.ComputeHash(reader)

      Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2)

      For i As Integer = 0 To hash.Length - 1
        sb.Append(hash(i).ToString("X2"))
      Next

      Return sb.ToString().ToLower
    End Using
  End Using
End Function
```

Word document is then opened:

```
Private Shared Function OpenDocument(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
  Try
    Dim process As New Process
    process.StartInfo.FileName = path
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = True
    process.Start()
    Return True
  Catch ex As Exception
    Return False
  End Try
End Function
```

There is list of all opened documents in the application. Right after document is opened, info about it is added to this list. So far, pretty simple. There is timer in the application that ticks every 1000ms and checks, whether any of the opened documents has been closed already. Because there is no simple way to get such info from Word, following trick is used:

```
Public Shared Function IsLockedFile(ByVal path As String) As Boolean
  Dim isLocked As Boolean = True

  Try
    Using fs As FileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write)
      isLocked = False
    End Using
  Catch ex As Exception
  End Try

  Return isLocked
End Function
```

If application successfully opens file with write access, it means that document is closed (it is no more locked by Word). Right after that, MD5 hash of the file is computed again using the same function as above. If old hash is equal to the new one, it means that user didn't make any changes in the document. If hashes are different, document is uploaded to the server. That is simplified description of the whole process.

It's working quite fine. However, customer reported that from time to time a change to the document is lost. After long time we discovered the reason. When application computes hash of (closed) document, it sometimes returns the old hash. Like it's reading still the old version of the file. Bug occurence is quite undeterministic. Mostly it's working fine. For example 50 times I get correct (different) hash, but then 3 times in a row wrong (old) one.

I was never able to simulate the bug in my developer environment (Windows Server 2008 virtualized in VMware), only in the host (Windows 7 64bit, antivirus turned off).

I even tried to put some delay before hash is recomputed to make sure that all disk operations are flushed. But even after 2 seconds I still got wrong, old hash. Maybe it's not enought, but how long should I wait?

From what I googled, there is only possibility to flush IO operations made with .NET application, not outside it. Exclusive opening for read/write when reading the hash didn't help either. Any ideas how to solve this or what else might cause it?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry.. I don't think you will get many answers to this. SO is point-grind, so asking hard questions like this takes too much effort for people to try and help with. I've tried a few, and ended up having to answer them myself.

Comment: Are trying to recreate [WebDAV](http://kb.iu.edu/data/aqso.html)?

Comment: Mithlon is pretty spot-on with the point-grind thing.  One thing that usually helps is that if you rack up enough reputation, you can place a bounty (sacrificing your own rep as bounty) which will gain attention.

Comment: I'm not buying the "old file content" explanation at all.  This is just too trivially explained by the user saving the document with another name.  Very easy to do in Word, you'll never see it and the user has no clue why that change didn't get picked up.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have more success if you use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) instead.

Have it determine when the document has changed, and then upload it to the server.

Comment: I don't see how a FileSystemWatcher will help you with the locking-issues etc. If a file is being written on a drive managed by a weird driver/os that doesn't report locking properly you'll still have the same sort of issues. FSW will help you avoid polling, though it does have issues with loosing events when there are thousands of files being watched which often force you to couple it with slower polling anyway.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something then.  I envision this app as keeping track of when a document changes on the user's local PC. If a change is detected, it sends it back to the server.  Wouldn't you be able to use the watcher to determine which files were changed?  I don't see locking being an issue, because the file should no longer be locked after it has been modified/saved.

Comment: You might be on to something. However, the way I read him is that he knows the file has changed, so I'm thinking getting extra confirmation from the FSW won't make it any more true that it has indeed changed. It certainly couldn't hurt to try what you suggest though. PS: Not sure that the file is local.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, I know when file is changed, or at least I'm pretty sure that when IsLockedFile returns false, the file is released from Word (and saved). As I wrote, I even put some delay after that to make sure that changes are flushed to the disk. I could try to use FSW, but I'm not sure now, if when it notifies me about the change will also mean that the file is "released" from Word (it's exclusively opened). And yes, file is local.